# jQuery dropdown menu CSS manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the jQuery Simple Drop-Down Menu Plugin from http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/

In their example, when you hover a menu item, a red dropdown box appears. I can't figure out how to make the main tab red as well while the dropdown is visible. It should remain red when you also hover on the dropdown and return to normal via timeout. The code uses a `timeout` function so I'll have to somehow implement it into that.

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

I tried making a function for changing the background CSS and adding it to mouseover and mouseout, but it either changes the background for all menu tabs or nothing happens. Does anyone know a good solution?

Comment: you want to make red color tab as blue color ?

Comment: No, I want to make the tab I hover red like the dropdown. Then when the dropdown disappears, i want to make it blue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your style sheet with this :

```
#jsddm li a:hover
    { background: #24313C }

    #jsddm li:hover > a
    { background: #24313C; display:block }
```

See the Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/evcL2/2/

Comment: Thanks that's neat! Please note the `timeout` js function I mentioned in my post. The plain css method works but the dropdown menu remains visible longer because it uses `timeout` so I must implement the css change in jquery

Comment: That's neat! +1 for using jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Just add these lines to css

```
#jsddm li a:hover
{   
background: #8EA344
}
```

put any color in the background you want.

Comment: Thanks but it should remain that color when you hover on the dropdown as well. For this reason I'm trying to modify the jquery.

Comment: See the answer I gave you. Update that styles in your current style sheet. Thanks!